# Postgres unencrypted keyword is no longer supported

Tags: postgresql, roundhouse

When executing this postgres command:

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE USER myuser WITH UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD ''my+password''';
```

I see the error:

```
RoundhousE encountered an error.
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 0A000: UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD is no longer supported
```

Is there a workaround for this, or will the password need to be manually encrypted and supplied without the UNENCRYPTED keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All you have to do is to omit the `UNENCRYPTED`.

You can supply both encrypted and unencrypted passwords that way, and PostgreSQL can tell the difference automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did omit the keyword but then was still getting errors when authenticating to the database via the same connection string. Would the password remain the same when logging in, assuming I removed UNENCRYPTED, but left the password value the same?

Comment: Sure, you can use that very same password to log into the database. Consult the PostgreSQL log to see the reason for your authentication failure.

Comment: I'll try and log in again and get back to accept this answer! thanks

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 10+ no longer support user creation with UNENCRYPTED password,
create it with ENCRYPTED:

```
CREATE USER myuser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ''my+password''
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean `my+password` should be `e363412a12831abb90257374ec38b6d4` which is the encrypted form?

Comment: means that `my+password` is your password (you put the text you want) but psql will store it encrypted